# Same class implement, just only different parent, how to deal with this?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have two classes that defined like this:

```
public class RoleButton: Button
{
   protected bool PrimaryRole;
    protected bool SecondaryRole;

    private string _role;
    private AuthenticatedPage CurrentPage
    {
        get { return (AuthenticatedPage)Page; }
    }

    protected UserInfo CurrentUser
    {
        get { return CurrentPage.CurrentUser; }
    }

    protected void SetRole(string role)
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (CurrentUser.IsSuperAdmin) return;
        DataTable dt = CommandController.GetButtonRoleForUserByPortalID(CurrentUser.UserID,
                                                                        ConvertUtility.ToInt32(AppEnv.PortalId()));

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                PrimaryRole = ConvertUtility.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0][_role]);
                SecondaryRole = ConvertUtility.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[1][_role]);

                if (!PrimaryRole && !SecondaryRole)
                {
                    Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PrimaryRole = ConvertUtility.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0][_role]);
                Visible = PrimaryRole;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Visible = false;
        }     
}


public class RoleImageButton: ImageButton
{
   ///
   ///same as above
   ///
}
```

The implementation of these classes are exactly the same, so I want to remove this duplication, but I don't know the technique to do this.

Can you show me the way to do this?

Comment: Does the OnPreRender() code need access to private or protected variables in the Button, RoleButton, ImageButton, or RoleImageButton classes?  My guess would be yes, but there's always hope...

Comment: JOC, can you post the code that is being duplicated in OnPreRender()?

Comment: I added full class implementation :). Thank you

Comment: The problem is going to be those member variables you're setting, `PrimaryRole` and `SecondaryRole`.  They are not the same variable in a common class, they are two separate sets of members with the same name.  I will add code to give you an idea of how to handle this if you want... it's basically what I said, you have to implement a common interface on both buttons that exposes those two properties.  Which unfortunately means that you've effectively made them public properties.

Comment: You may be able to implement the interface as internal, which would at least limit the scope of what you're exposing to your own dll... I'll have to think about that

Comment: Updated with a better idea than exposing the properties through an interface... let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 3):

The tripping point is whether or not you need to access private variables of any of those classes, or properties that are specific to them.

When you want to encapsulate and share behavior, you use the Command Pattern.  It looks something like:

```
public interface ICommand {
    void ExecuteOnPreRender(WebControl control, EventArgs args);
}

//  This class encapsulates the functionality common
//  to both OnPreRender commands
public class SharedPreRenderCommand : ICommand {
    public void ExecuteOnPreRender(WebControl control, EventArgs args) {
        //  Modify the size, border, etc... any property that is 
        //  common to the controls in question
    }
}

public class RoleImageButton : ImageButton {

    private ICommand onPreRenderCommand = null;

    public void SetPreRenderCommand (ICommand command) {
        onPreRenderCommand = command;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs args) {
        if (null != onPreRenderCommand) {
            onPreRenderCommand.ExecuteOnPreRender(this, args);
        }
        else {
            base.OnPreRender(args);
        }
    }
}


public class RoleButton : Button {

    private ICommand onPreRenderCommand = null;

    public void SetPreRenderCommand (ICommand command) {
        onPreRenderCommand = command;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs args) {
        if (null != onPreRenderCommand) {
            onPreRenderCommand.ExecuteOnPreRender(this, args);
        }
        else {
            base.OnPreRender(args);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to encapsulate and extract functionality... the limitation, of course, is that you can't access private or protected members, or members specific to RoleButton, etc., because you have to pass a common base to the command.  Not being able to access RoleButton/RoleImageButton-specific members should be a non-issue; your code can't be common code if it uses anything specific to either of these : )

If you have to access private/protected members, you would need to create an interface that exposes the properties, and implement it separately for both RoleButton and RoleImageButton, and pass that interface to the command... but then you're basically forcing those properties to be public, and making them accessible to other classes.  If you absolutely need to do this, I can give you some sample code to show you how, but it's really not a good idea.

What you're really after is multiple inheritance, a concept that C# doesn't support.

***EDIT***

There are two ways to skin this cat... I'd recommend the first one, which is to encapsulate the variables you're going to change in your command and pass it as a parameter, as such:

```
//  Encapsulate these fields if you want to be PC
public class Roles {
    public bool PrimaryRole;
    public bool SecondaryRole;
}

public class RoleButton: Button {
    protected Roles buttonRoles;    
    ...
}

public class SharedPreRenderCommand : ICommand {

    public void ExecuteOnPreRender(WebControl control, Roles roles, EventArgs args) {
        //  Modify the Roles class, which the RoleButton or 
        //  RoleImageButton has a handle to
    }

}
```

Alternatively, make the Roles class a struct and pass it by ref.  This keeps you from exposing your roles, allowing you to keep them as protected.  Everything else from the command-pattern code I wrote is used as-is.

The second approach isn't even worth mentioning... I'll give it up under duress, but it's such a bad idea, I wouldn't want to promote it unless it were tortured out of me.
: D

HTH,
James

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `BaseButton` class that derives from `Button`.  If there are any changes specific to each button, then derive from `BaseButton` as follows:

```
public class BaseButton : Button
{
   ///
   protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   {
      // Common base implementationi
   }         
}

public class ImageButton: BaseButton
{
   // Specific implementation
   public ImageButton()
   {
      this.Name = "ImageButton";
   }
}

public class RoleButton: BaseButton
{
   // Specific implementation
   public RoleButton()
   {
      this.Name = "RoleButton";
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 because I can't see any reason why someone would downvote this.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because one of those buttons derived from `ImageButton`, not `Button`.  This answer unfortunately loses the connection between `RoleImageButton : ImageButton`.  There's an error in the example code, also, because he's declared `public class ImageButton : BaseButton`, where what he means is `public class RoleImageButton : BaseButton`

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a RoleButton class that wraps around other button types?

If Button and ImageButton both have a common base or implement an interface like IButton you could have something like this:

```
class RoleButton : IButton
{
  private Button _realButton;

  public RoleButton(Button realButton) { _realButton = realButton; }

  // IButton implementation delegates non-role stuff to _realButton
}
```

That way you don't end up duplicating your RoleButton code:

```
var roleButton = new RoleButton(myButton);
var roleImageButton = new RoleButton(myImageButton);
```

Comment: Again, you lose the connection between `RoleImageButton : ImageButton`... `Button` and `ImageButton` are two distinct classes in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` - both inherit from WebControl.  (Well, ImageButton inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`, which inherits directly from WebControl... the point is that ImageButton and Button are as different as Frog and Unicorn)

Comment: They both implement IButtonControl so you might be able to get away with that. The implementation posted above doesn't seem to depend on anything specific to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).** It would allow you to have a single file (the template) containing the implementation *once*, and it would generate the two classes with the identical implementations for you. (Of course, the code would still be duplicated in the compiled assembly, but at least there’s no more of that maintenance problem of keeping them in sync.)